# Vue url changes on navigation

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I am just getting started with Vue. I installed @Vue/Cli (that's version 3) and also cli-init so I can use version 2's commands. To create my project I used vue init webpack . 
While running the app on the browser I noticed strange behaviour;
my routes are being changed!

[Initial Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp5Ci.png) "localhost:8080/"

[Navigating to the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGyQg.png) url changes to "localhost:8080/#/"

[Also with another route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9yOA.png) "localhost:8080/about"

[Navigating to this route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eynyp.png) the url changes to "localhost:8080/about#/"

I don't understand what is going on. It renders the components though, but the url just changes.
Here is my routes config:

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'AboutComponent',
      component: AboutComponent,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      component: HelloWorld,
    },
  ],
});
```

No router links, I navigated by typing the paths. 
My router setting is default.

Comment: Show your router-links ant what mode you selected for router? History?

Comment: I used no router links. I used the default setting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably answer the question yourself by reading vue-router documentation here (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

By default vue-router works in *hash* mode. Routes are changed in the browser with a 'hash' for compatibility with old browsers. Nowadays you can safely use history mode, and your URLs won't change in the browser location box.

However, I recommend that you read and fully understand how client-side routing works and what's the required server-side configuration you need to make your app work properly.

Welcome to Vue.JS!

Comment: Oh, will do. Thank you. Quite different from my Angular6 experience.

Comment: Using history mode solved the problem. Thank you, again.